# Summarize number of occurrences per minute in R

Tags: r

I have some telemetry data recording acoustic tag detections by a receiver. The data frame includes the unique tag code and the time of detection. Time is in Posix time (number of seconds since 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970).

```
det <- data.frame(
code = c("34", "15", "34", "36", "15", "34", "36", "15", "34", "15", "15", "15", "34", "15", "34", "15", "34", "15", "34", "15", "34", "34", "15", "36"),
posix = c(1599655073, 1599655136, 1599655136, 1599655152, 1599655199, 1599655199, 1599655210, 1599655262, 1599655262, 1599655325, 1599655388, 1599655451, 1599655451, 1599655514, 1599655514, 1599655577, 1599655577, 1599655640, 1599655640, 1599655703, 1599655703, 1599655765, 1599655766, 1599655789)
)
```

I need to know how many times a tag was detected in each minute. The output should record the sequential minute from the beginning of the series, the tag code, and the number of occurrences in that minute. If a code did not appear during a minute it should get a zero.

The first six lines of the output should look like this:

```
 min code freq
1   1   34    1
2   1   15    0
3   1   36    0
4   2   34    1
5   2   15    1
6   2   36    1
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting `minute` and `code` to factors and specifying `group_by(..., .drop = FALSE)` allows to get all the combinations of `minute` and `code`, even if not found in data. These will be assigned `freq` 0.

```r
library(dplyr)

det |>
  mutate(minute = 1 + ((posix - min(posix)) %/% 60)) |>
  mutate(minute = factor(minute, levels = seq(1, max(minute)))) |>
  mutate(code = factor(code)) |>
  group_by(minute, code, .drop = FALSE) |>
  summarize(freq = n(), .groups = "drop")

+ # A tibble: 36 × 3
   minute code   freq
   <fct>  <fct> <int>
 1 1      15        0
 2 1      34        1
 3 1      36        0
 4 2      15        1
 5 2      34        1
 6 2      36        1
 7 3      15        1
 8 3      34        1
 9 3      36        1
10 4      15        1
# … with 26 more rows
```

Comment: This does what I need it to do, in a round-about way. I never would have thought of this, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is good task for `tidyr::complete`: first convert the dates using the lubridate package, then fill the gaps with `tidyr::complete` and create the `freq` variable.

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

det %>% 
  mutate(posix = minute(as.POSIXlt(posix, origin = "1970-01-01")),
         minute = posix - first(posix) + 1) %>% 
  complete(minute, code) %>% 
  group_by(minute, code) %>% 
  mutate(freq = sum(complete.cases(posix))) %>% 
  select(-posix)

# A tibble: 39 x 3
   minute code   freq
    <dbl> <chr> <int>
 1      1 15        0
 2      1 34        1
 3      1 36        0
 4      2 15        1
 5      2 34        1
 6      2 36        0
 7      3 15        1
 8      3 34        1
 9      3 36        1
10      4 15        0
# ... with 29 more rows
```

Comment: There is always a new tidyverse verb to learn. 1+ for `tidyr::complete`

Comment: I tried this method using my full dataset and I'm afraid it doesn't do what I need it to. When a code is detected more than once in a minute it shows up in a new row with a freq of 1, instead of adding to the total frequency of occurrences of that code.

Comment: Then you can take the sum of the complete cases by minute and code, I edited my answer.